# how is one I/O measured in google app engine

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am making my first App. I am new to both SQL and GAE. Google Cloud SQL has tier "D0", which has "included I/O per day" of 200k. I have an example, could you please explain how many I/O's is this example?

Suppose I have a table in my Cloud SQL of 10 rows and 3 headers. the headers are "article name", "author", "date of publishing". so there are 30 fields in total. When a user starts my App and requests latest information, I want to send the user all 30 fields. I can send this to the user with a single SQL code.

Is the execution of that query counted as thirty I/O because 30 fields were transferred or one I/O because one SQL query was run?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

[The pricing guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing) has this to say;

> The number of I/O requests to storage made by your database instance depends on your queries, workload and data set. Cloud SQL will cache data in memory to serve your queries efficiently and to minimise the number of I/O requests.

In other words, neither of the two options, some queries may be served entirely from memory, generating no I/O, while some may generate many I/O requests. Optimising the database well with indexes will make your queries cheaper, generating table scans over large tables will cost more.

In short, same good practice rules apply as keeping a fast database as on a local machine, but not doing the optimisation won't just make your queries slower, but make them cost more.

Answer (score 0):

The # of I/Os refers to disk operations. So that really depends on the query and the cached data.